# Multer can't get sperate field name in console.log

Tags: node.js, express, npm, multer

I created an Express app in combination with [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload items in my Node.js app.

In my multi-upload setup I need to get the `fieldname` property for each item separately.

With `console.log(req.files);` I get all uploaded items as seen in the code below.

But how do I get `fieldname`? I'd like to do something like

```
console.log(req.files.upfile);
console.log(req.files.upfile2);
```

I hope someone here knows how to do this. Would highly appreciate help, thanks!

```
[ { fieldname: 'upfile',
    originalname: 'test_file1.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'storage/',
    filename: 'test_file1.jpg',
    path: 'storage/test_file1.jpg',
    size: 1046949 },
  { fieldname: 'upfile2',
    originalname: 'test_file2.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'storage/',
    filename: 'test_file2.jpg',
    path: 'storage/test_file2.jpg',
    size: 632169 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are uploading multiple files and using array then you can iterate your request as below in router API Call

```
let files = req.files;
files.forEach((file) => {
    console.log(file.fieldname);
});
```

Comment: thanks after checking your code it displays both `fieldname` at once but I want to control it with something like `console.log(file.fieldname.upfile);` and `console.log(file.fieldname.upfile2);` separately so I can manipulate it later with my app functions your code outputs all `fieldname` at once but I need it separately hope you know how to do it would be awesome.

Comment: not sure if it's possible to use your code and to select the `console.log(file.fieldname);`using an array to output just the first item and do the same with the other items but don't know if it's possible please let me know